# WP function to display custom taxonomies in WP-Admin Style

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a custom taxonomy to Users - user categories.

Using the code below, I am able to output the custom taxonomies in each edit-user profile page:

```
function show_user_category( $user ) {

//get the terms that the user is assigned to
$assigned_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $user->ID, 'user_category' );
$assigned_term_ids = array();
foreach( $assigned_terms as $term ) {
    $assigned_term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
}

//get all the terms we have
$user_cats = get_terms( 'user_category', array('hide_empty'=>false) );

echo "<h3>User Category</h3>";

//list the terms as checkbox, make sure the assigned terms are checked
foreach( $user_cats as $cat ) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" id="user-category-<?php echo $cat->term_id ?>" <?php if(in_array( $cat->term_id, $assigned_term_ids )) echo 'checked=checked';?> name="user_category[]"  value="<?php echo $cat->term_id;?>"/>
    <?php
    echo '<label for="user-category-'.$cat->term_id.'">'.$cat->name.'</label>';
    echo '<br />';
}
}
```

The code above simply displays a list of checkboxes, ordered by term_id.

Of course, I want to display them in the same way that custom taxonomy terms would be displayed in a custom post type (a scrollable list of checkboxes, with child terms indented and underneath their parent term). The code above does not display the terms in order of parents/children.

Is there a WP function I can pass my taxonomy & terms to, to create what I described in the paragraph above? Or do I have to do it manually?

Thanks

Comment: In cases like this, I snoop the core WP code.  You could / should too.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
Yes, there are.  They are called `post_categories_meta_box()` and `post_tags_meta_box()`, depending on the type of taxonomy you are using.

**Long answer:**
This is the sort of question that can be answered by inspecting the WP core code.

Here's the walk-through on how I did it to answer this question:

Editing a page in admin results in a url of `wp-admin/post.php`.  So, inspect that file (post.php).

A quick search in that file for "tax" results in nothing, so we can at least look at the `case 'edit'` section, because we know we're doing an edit.  And we can see it includes a file `edit-form-advanced.php`.

So, inspect that file (edit-form-advanced.php)

A quick search for "tax" gets into an area that looks promising.

Here we see they call `get_taxonomy`, and then that `get_taxonomy` object that is returned has a callback called `meta_box_cb` - so do a cross-file search for that.  We find several instances, but the instance in `taxonomy.php` is the most promising (because of the file name), so lets look there.

It appears (around line 430 of taxonomy.php) that there's a pair of callback functions - `post_categories_meta_box` and `post_tags_meta_box` that WP core is using.  Let's check them out - do a cross-file search for `function post_categories_meta_box`, and we find both of these functions exist in the file `meta-boxes.php`.  The comments for the functions are excellent, and tell us what you are asking: "Display post categories form fields".

Armed with this information, we can ask Google, and we find the WP documentation for the functions:

[post_categories_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_categories_meta_box/)

and

[post_tags_meta_box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_tags_meta_box/)